# XSLT: Using Variable to store and reuse the Attribute Value

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to making changes in an XML document and I'm having trouble by storing and reusing the Values of Attributes.

The variable stores all of the values from same repeating Elements. But I want it to store and reuse just the value of current Element.

here is my XSLT:

```mxml
    <!-- set them -->
    <xsl:variable name="Signatur" select=".//Field[@Type='2950']/@Value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Datum" select=".//Field[@Type='9920']/@Value"/>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='8450']/Field[@Type='8540']"/>

    <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='8450']">
        <h1:Field Type="8450" Value="digitale Reproduktion">
            <!-- use them -->
            <h1:Field Type="8540" Value="{$Signatur}"/>
            <h1:Field Type="8494" Value="{$Datum}"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </h1:Field>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, a colleague helped me out. preceding-sibling makes the trick:

```
 <xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='8450']">
    <xsl:variable name="Signatur" select="preceding-sibling::Field[@Type='ob28']/Field[@Type='2950']/@Value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="Datum" select="preceding-sibling::Field[@Type='9920']/@Value"/>
    <h1:Field Type="8450" Value="digitale Reproduktion">
        <!-- use them -->
        <h1:Field Type="8540" Value="{$Signatur}"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8494" Value="{$Datum}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1:Field>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

> the variables Signatur and Datum store both values from first and second document. But I want them to store and reuse just the values from current document.

It looks like you don't want to use variables at all, then. Why not simply make a relative reference to the nodes you want to output?

```
<xsl:template match="Document/Field[@Type='8450']">
    <h1:Field Type="8450" Value="digitale Reproduktion">
        <h1:Field Type="8540" Value="{Field[@Type='8540']}"/>
        <h1:Field Type="8540" Value="{Field[@Type='8470']}"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </h1:Field>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Note that match expressions do not have to be full XPath expressions that are relative to anything. Simply state what nodes the template should match, i.e. instead of

```
<xsl:template match=".//Field[@Type='8450']">
```

use

```
<xsl:template match="Field[@Type='8450']">
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work with your way. I can not call the Fields which arent hierarchically under the element "<h1:Field Type="8450">".

Comment: do you have any idea how to call the both elements  -which are outside- inside of the  "<h1:Field Type="8450">"